# 19.10 Only one speaker works (2.1)

Tags: sound, realtek

I just installed ubuntu 19.10 with third party drivers and everything normal.
The problem is that the audio only sounds from the "Left" speaker. I tried reading some posts but still not working.

The thing it is that I moved (from laptop) to desktop PC, the hdmi is connected and seems that has audio output (maybe using nvidia-435 audio drivers),
but changing the settings to use the speakers "output line/analogic output (balance checked, tryed "alsa" drivers reinstalled too, mixers...) it only works from that Left speaker, not subbuffer, not Right neither.

- Additionally (I have to pick one config for this case. estereo, 2.1[X], 4.0, 5.1, etc)

Any idea about that?. I suppose that Realtek Audio driver is missing, I wrote them too (his driver failed for me using their guide, so still waiting anwer)
Current kernel 5.3.0-26-generic.

I hope any solution.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

I also had an issue where I had only sound from one channel. It appeared that the other channel had its volume set to 0. I corrected that manually with:

```
pactl set-sink-volume 10 61604
```